# Str[i] auto boolean check in the for loop

Tags: c++

```
printArrayWithoutLength(char str [])
{
    for(int i=0;str[i];i++)
        cout<< str[i]<< endl;
}
```

Why does the above work? I am not using a boolean check on the length.

Comment: I assume `str` is supposed to be NUL-terminated. That is, it's valid up to a byte with the value of 0 - which also happens to be "falsy" in boolean context.

Comment: yes Igor. It is a null terminated string. Does this hold good for C and c++?

Answer (score 2):

In C, any condition that isn't a direct boolean expression (that is, some other type than boolean and doesn't involve a comparison operator [`>`, `<`, `==`, `!=`, etc]) will automatically compare as a not equal to zero, so you could rewrite your code as:

```
for(int i=0;str[i] != 0;i++)
```

or

```
for(int i=0;str[i] != '\0';i++)
```

or

```
for(int i=0; 0 != str[i]; i++)
```

with exactly the same result and exactly the same code being generated. Just a bit more or less typing, and depending on the familiarity with C or C++, you may find that it's more or less easy to read one over another.

Of course, this only works for traditional C-style strings that are terminated with a nul-character (character with the value zero). There are other ways to store strings, and this code, in whichever form would naturally not work if the string is not actually terminated with a zero character.

Answer (score 0):

Writing `str[i]` as a conditional expression of `for` is equivalent to `str[i] != '\0'` (your string should be null terminated). When `str[i]` becomes `\0`, loop will terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Whether this function (without return type)

```
printArrayWithoutLength(char str [])
{
    for(int i=0;str[i];i++)
        cout<< str[i]<< endl;
}
```

will or will not work depends on what the array used as the argument contains. If it contains a string that is a sequence of characters terminated by zero then this function will work because inside the loop there is condition

```
str[i]
```

that will be equal to `false` if the value of str[i] contains zero for some i.

According to the C++ Standard (4.12 Boolean conversions [conv.bool])

> 1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer
>   to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. **A zero
>   value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted
>   to false;** any other value is converted to true.

Otherwise if the array does not contain a string the behaviour of the function is undefined.